# Simplify $\dfrac{x + \frac{x}{y}}{\frac{y}{x} + \frac{1}{x}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Sorry, my algebra is a bit rusty. Could someone explain how
$$\dfrac{x + \frac{x}{y}}{\frac{y}{x} + \frac{1}{x}}$$ can be rewritten as $\frac{x^2}{y}$ ?

Comment: Multi0ply top-and-bottom by $xy$, then simplify.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you should put things in the same denominator:

$$\frac{x+\frac{x}{y}}{\frac{y}{x}+\frac{1}{x}}$$
$$ = \frac{\frac{yx}{y}+\frac{x}{y}}{\frac{y+1}{x}} = \frac{\frac{yx+x}{y}}{\frac{y+1}{x}}$$
$$ = (\frac{yx+x}{y})(\frac{x}{y+1}) = \frac{yx^2+x^2}{y(y+1)}$$
$$ = \frac{x^2(y+1)}{y(y+1)} = \frac{x^2}{y}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\displaystyle \frac{x+\frac{x}{y}}{\frac{y}{x}+\frac{1}{x}}=\frac{xy+x}{y}\frac{x}{y+1}=\frac{x^2(y+1)}{y(y+1)}=\frac{x^2}{y}$$

Answer (score 1):

Observe that since both $x$ and $y$ occur as denominators of fractions, neither of them can be $0$.

$$\begin{align*}
\dfrac{x + \frac{x}{y}}{\frac{y}{x} + \frac{1}{x}}&=\dfrac{x + \frac{x}{y}}{\frac{y}{x} + \frac{1}{x}}\cdot\frac{xy}{xy} & \text{multiplying by }\frac{xy}{xy}=1\text{ doesn't change value}\\\\\\\\\\
&=\dfrac{(x + \frac{x}{y})(xy)}{(\frac{y}{x} + \frac{1}{x})(xy)}&\text{mutliplication of fractions works like }\frac{a}{b}\cdot \frac{c}{d}=\frac{ac}{bd}\\\\\\\\\\
&=\frac{x(xy)+\frac{x}{y}(xy)}{\frac{y}{x}(xy)+\frac{1}{x}(xy)}&\text{distributive law of multiplication: } (a+b)c=ac+bc\\\\\\\\\\
&=\frac{x^2y+x^2}{y^2+y} & \text{simplifying each of the four terms}\\\\\\\\\\
&=\frac{x^2(y+1)}{y(y+1)} & {\text{factoring the numerator and denominator;} \atop\text{equivalently, using the distributive law in reverse}}\\\\\\\\\\
&=\frac{x^2}{y}\cdot\frac{y+1}{y+1} & \text{multiplication of fractions again}\\\\\\\\\\
&=\frac{x^2}{y} & \text{since }\frac{y+1}{y+1}=1
\end{align*}$$
(now we can also see that we needed $y\neq -1$, since $y+1$ is in the denominator of a fraction.)